# boost xpressive: wrong match?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I want to match a simple expression with *boost*, but it behaves strange... The code below should match and display "a" from first and second strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

#include "stdio.h"

using namespace boost::xpressive;

void xmatch_action( const char *line ) {
    cregex g_re_var;
    cmatch what;
    g_re_var = cregex::compile( "\\s*var\\s+([\\w]+)\\s*=.*?" );


    if (regex_match(line, what, g_re_var )) {
        printf("OK\n");
        printf(">%s<\n", what[1] );
    }
    else {
        printf("NOK\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    xmatch_action("var a = qqq");
    xmatch_action(" var a = aaa");
    xmatch_action(" var abc ");
}
```

but my actual output is:

```
OK
>a = qqq<
OK
>a = aaa<
NOK
```

and it should be

```
OK
>a<
OK
>a<
NOK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `printf()` use the `<<` operator to print the `sub_match` object (`what[1]`). Or you can try using `what[1].str()` instead of `what[1]`.

See the docs: [sub_match](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/sub_match.html), [match_results](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html), [regex_match](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html)

Comment: results of a small test; those are OK: `cout << what[1] << endl; printf("%s\n", what[1].str().c_str() ); printf("%s\n", string(what[1]).c_str() );` This is not OK: `printf("%s\n", what[1] );`

Answer (score 0):

Remove square brackets around \w in regex AND use std::cout for printing.  Then you will get result that you want.